# Window scaling/zooming in Windows 7

Tags: windows

For Windows 7, are there any programs that make it possible to change the scale of any open window? For example, if I had a file open in Notepad, I'd like to change the scale of the Notepad window to half of its height and half of its width (by "zooming out").

Comment: your use of the word zoom is confusing to me. Do you want to simply resize the window, or actually shrink the font size and menus too?

Comment: I actually want to shrink the font size and menus. Here's a demonstration of the concept (the only one that I know of anywhere on the Internet): http://jermolene.tiddlyspace.com/cecily

Comment: This type of user interface is called a "zooming user interface" - I was wondering if there was any software that would make it possible on Windows.